# Auto Update in sugarsync android API

Tags: android

I have checked sugar sync App from  Play Store UI, it's superb,

I have integrated the sugar sync API in my app too but now My question is, when i am adding a new file in browser, then automatically the device page is updating,

I would like to know how can i achieve that,
is there any API for automatic Update or can i set any listener in my application.

any link or help is appreciable.

Thanks in advance